# Losing attachments in Axis2 response

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm trying to send an attachment to client from Axis2 web service. The problem is that the message context, which client receives from the service, does not contain any attachments, though the last one seems to add it.
Here is the brief code of both sides.
Service:

```
MessageContext inMC = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
OperationContext operationContext = inMC.getOperationContext();
MessageContext outMC = operationContext.getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_OUT_VALUE);
DataHandler handler = new DataHandler (new FileDataSource("C://goods.xml"));
String attachID = outMC.addAttachment(handler);
OMElement idElem = factory.createOMElement("doc", ns);
idElem.addAttribute("href", "cid:" + attachID, ns);
```

Client (trying to receive attachment):

```
MessageContext mcResponse = operationClient.getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
SOAPBody body = mcResponse.getEnvelope().getBody();
OMElement attachElem = body.getFirstChildWithName (new QName("doc"));
String attachID = attachElem.getAttributeValue (new QName("href"));
attachID = attachID.replaceFirst("cid:", "");
DataHandler dataHandler = mcResponse.getAttachment(attachID);
```

getAttachment() method returns null. In case of debugging the client application, IDE shows, that attachment map in input message context does not contain any elements (size=0). The OMElement object (idElem), which contains attachment id, is received and read by client normally (debug showed cid). The parameters enableSwA, cacheAttachments, attachmentDIR, sizeThreshold are set both in services.xml and programming part of client. What is wrong with the message context?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

**Upd**: TCPmon showed the following content.
Request to service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><getXMLFile xmlns="http://axis2.apache.org"><filename>goods.xml</filename></getXMLFile></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I guess it's ok :)

Response from service:

```
109
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><doc href="cid:d06f3b36afdfcbd2e135ecfbcad05ee602661262b059ed38@apache.org"></doc></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
0
```

I apologize for a bit simple questions, but where the attachment should be reflected? I guess, if the service send an attachment, the SOAP message contains binary data, isn't it?
I checked also for putting the attachment into message context on service side - it's OK, I can get it there back from context after adding.

Comment: Did you trace the HTTP traffic?

Comment: No, I did not. The supposition of successfull adding the attachment on service part is based on normal execution of this part and passing OMElement with attachment ID back to client. If you explain, how to trace HTTP traffic and what the results of tracing will mean, i will be glad to do it :)

Comment: You could e.g. use Wirkshark or a simple TCP proxy to see whether the attachment was submitted at all. You'd be able to isolate the problem to the client or server.

Comment: I found Wireshark a little bit difficult for me :D It does not show the local traffic for some reason (from localhost to localhost), but I traced it using TCPmon (see below). Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. The trouble was on the service side. TCPmon showed there was no attachments in responce message. However, the same [example service](http://wso2.org/library/1675) works fine. After checking and comparing every operation on my service, it came out that programming part is not the reason either. The only one was left - service settings. So, the reason is that settings fields in service.xml file on the service, which require boolean type, does not allow *any* additional symbols. My mistake:

Incorrect:

```
    <parameter name="enableSwA">
        true
    </parameter>
```

Correct:

```
<parameter name="enableSwA">true</parameter>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use tcpmon[1] to trace the http message and isolate the problem.

Anyway the better method for handling attachments is to use MTOM. Which can be used with data binding frameworks like ADB[2], or with POJO as well.

thanks,
Amila.

[1] http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/

[2] http://amilachinthaka.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-mtom-with-axis2.html